# Android O Pinned Shortcuts - CREATE_SHORTCUT intent filter

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

[In the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html#pinned) for the new "Pinned Shortcuts" feature in Android O, they mention that "You can also create a specialized activity that helps users create shortcuts, complete with custom options and a confirmation button".

I tried following the documentation, but when I tried to create a new shortcut I only saw the default dialog, and not my activity.

Here's the declaration in the Manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".ShortcutActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

---

P.S
In the documentation they also shows an example in the Gmail app - how do I get to that screen? I wanted to see the flow but I couldn't find it.

Comment: have you included the meta-data

Comment: @OriWasserman check out my updated answer

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a new activity as dialog, then you can add whatever options you want on that dialog and handle as you want the `addShortcut` method.

I tried that code to add and remove a dynamical shortcut and it worked.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".DialogActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"
        >
...
</activity>
```

**DialogActivity.java**

```
public class DialogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);
        this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
        findViewById(R.id.add_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addShortcut();
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.cancel_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

**activity_dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_dialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.metax.myapplication.DialogActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you want to add shortcut?"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="No thanks"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Add me"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In you Java class insert

```
 ShortcutManager sM = c.getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);

    Intent intent2 = new Intent(c.getApplicationContext(), ShortcutActivity.class);
    intent2.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    ShortcutInfo  shortcut2 = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(c,MSG_SHORCUT_CUSTOM)
            .setIntent(intent2)
            .setShortLabel("ShortLabel")
            .setLongLabel("LongLaber")
            .setDisabledMessage("DisabledMessage")
            .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(c, R.mipmap.ic_add_outline_short))
            .build();
    listshortcut.add(shortcut2);

    Intent pinnedShortcutCallbackIntent = mShortcutManager.createShortcutResultIntent(shortcut2);
    PendingIntent successCallback = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,  pinnedShortcutCallbackIntent, 0);

mShortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(pinShortcutInfo, successCallback.getIntentSender());
    sM.setDynamicShortcuts(listshortcut);
```

Comment: Why do you need to call `createShortcutResultIntent` ? Why not just directly call `requestPinShortcut` with null as the second parameter? What does it provide you to have it this way?

Answer (score 0):

To launch your shortcut activity with action as ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT, long tap on app icon, and press widget icon, you ll notice a 1x1 widget, on tap of which your desired activity would be launched.

Also you can explicitly fire that intent from your app as well on some desired action.

Answer (score -3):

**Create a new resource file: res/xml/shortcuts.xml.** This  is how you create shortcuts,After you have done the nessicary changes in manifest

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="compose"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/compose_icon"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/compose_shortcut_short_label1"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/compose_shortcut_long_label1"
        android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/compose_disabled_message1">
        <intent
          android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
          android:targetPackage="your package"
          android:targetClass="com.example.myapplication.ComposeActivity" />
         </shortcut>
      <!-- Specify more shortcuts here. -->
    </shortcuts>
```

In **manifest** add this to the activity tag,

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
                 android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
```

If you want to read more refer this [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html) it explains **about pinned shortcuts, static and dynamic shortcuts.**

Here is an [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AppShortcuts) from google, in their samples repo

Comment: Isn't this only for static and dynamic shortcuts? I'm asking about pinned shortcuts. My problem isn't with creating the shortcuts, only the custom activity they're mentioning

Comment: @OriWasserman do you get a way to customize the Pinned shortcut dialog? I always see "Add to home screen" title and some text with 1x1 icon.